# Loading url link in the another instance of same ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a ViewController with uiwebvew. This is called to show the webcontents.

My problem is , if the webcontent has links, I want to show that link page in the another instance of same ViewController.

So far I'm unable to do so. I guess I'm missing something here.

Could anyone point my problem here.

Thanks in advance.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
       PageDetailsViewController *pdvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageDetails"];
       NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
       NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
       [pdvc.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:pdvc animated:YES];
       return NO;

    }
      return YES;
```

When I try to load in same viewcontroller, it's fine it loads. So, my guess is , there may be something wrong with my webview delegate or navigationcontroller.

Any ideas??

Comment: you are pushing same viewcontroller?

Comment: When you do `PageDetailsViewController *pdvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageDetails"];` this, you're creating a new instance of the object. You're not pushing the "same" view controller. It's not the same for the OS, as it's a different object in the memory. What you have are two different instances of the same object. I'd go with @rdelmar's suggestion here. Add a `NSURL*` property to this View Controller, and let it handle loading that url in it's UIWebView.

Comment: ok thanks everybody... i'm now going to use different view controller for this.

Answer (score 0):

pdvc.webview will be nil because its view has not been loaded at the time you're trying to reference it. You should pass the URL to pdvc, and let that controller load its web view in viewDidLoad.

Comment: but I'm pushing the same viewcontroller, is there any way beside handing in viewDidload / viewwillappear ?

Comment: @user3804063 why you are pushing same view controller? use same webview and loadrequest again.

Comment: @user3804063, I'm sure there would be ways to handle it, but why not use a different view controller? If you need common code, you could make both controllers inherit from a common base controller.